# Duplicate key error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, primary-key

this bugs me for a while.

I have a C# app inserting data to MSSQL database.
it is  using entity linq

the column [id] is Primary key, and no auto increase.

existed data like :

```
id       other columns
1001        ......
1002        ......
1003        ......
```

then i get new data :

```
ROW1:   1003   .......
ROW2:   1004   .......
ROW3:   1005   .......
```

the 1003 is existed so surely ROW1 will return "Duplicate key 1003 error"
but, when i try to insert others like 
1004,1005 they are **NO EXISTED**

the program will also return me  "Duplicate key **1003** error",
and fail to insert.

then i try on database will sql client, just insert a '1004', it will go through.

I am thinking is this kind of insert buffer, 
or like 'none or all' architecture?

then how can i do it?

my code is a loop , 
inserting one row then  use  `dbconn.savechange()`

Comment: Primary keys have to be unique; this is their nature. The errors are by design. I'm not sure I understand your question... are you asking how you can prevent a duplicate key error?

Answer (score 0):

It is an all or nothing. Read the IDs from the Database and manually remove the duplicate entries.

I would recommend checking the min and max values, and read the values back between them. That way you don't have to read all the IDs back.

Because of the overhead, this should be quicker than trying to insert one entry at a time, and checking for an error.

Answer (score 0):

In you are inserting this new Records/Rows as One batch then in case of any error whole batch will be ROLLBACK but if you insert these records per statement as a separate batch then 1003 with throw and error and sql execution will continue executing rest of the sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you.

I find a Solution, that is 
when i find the Duplicate key error come out for the first time.
which means real Duplicate key.

i re-establish database connection by:

```
                dbconn.Dispose();
                dbconn = new Entities();
```

then this will work

thanks a lot! 
hope this will help others

Comment: This probably means you're missusing linq to entities, entities are lightweight to create so you shouldn't do a new Entities & stick to it but re create one every time you do a new query (so that it doesn't carry state from the previous queries). Those are lightweight objects meant to be short-lived & you should encapsulate it in a using as such : using(var entities = new Entities()){ use entities here & if you need it later you'll redo a new using block, don't store the entities variable to reuse it later!}